# Python - Use to tablib to import Excel (xls, xlsx) files

Tags: python, excel, import

I'm having trouble figuring out how to import Excel files into my Python script. I'm only a few days into Python so I'm guessing it's something very obvious I'm missing. I'm using Python 3 and the tablib module. From the examples on the tablib site, I've worked out how to save files in xls format

```
    def saveXLS(self, name, data):        
        # Form the dataset with the accompanying headers
        dataTab =  tablib.Dataset()
        dataTab.headers = data[0][:]

        for i in range(1,len(data)):
            dataTab.append(data[i][:])

        with open(self.saveDir + name + ".xls", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(dataTab.xls)
```

(I know that loop is horrible and un-Pythonic, but it's important I get results at the moment as it's for work). At the moment, I open the Excel workbook and save it as a text file (I should point out that all my data is tab-delimited and consists of strings, even for numbers).

I open it like this

```
    def loadTxt(self,name, fileType, data):
            if( fileType == "txt"):            
                with open(self.currentWorkingDir + "\\" + name + ".txt",'r') as f:
                    reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
                    for X in reader:
                        data.append(X)
```

I tried copying the "dbf" example on the tablib website (http://tablib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/) to get

```
    def loadXLS(self):
            self.data = tablib.Dataset()
            self.data = open('Data.xlsx').read()
            return self.datav
```

And I get an error (as I expected, as I pulled it from my ass)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 637: character maps to .

I really have no clue how to figure this out unfortunately, so any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

You've probably figured it out by now, but for the next person, you need to read the Excel file as binary:

```
my_input_stream = open("my_file.xlsx", "rb")
my_dataset = tablib.import_set(my_input_stream)
dataset[1:5]
```

Comment: am trying this but I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 16: invalid start byte`.. thinking python version? Am on python3.5

Comment: I got a TypeError ("expected string or buffer) when trying the above. 
 Fixed with `my_input_stream = open("my_file.xlsx", "rb").read()`.
Also dataset is indexed from zero, so to see the first five rows of data use `dataset[0:4]`.

Answer (score 6):

Currently, tablib 0.12.1.

I use this to import a .xlsx databook that I created with tablib, and output to an excel file.

To get it back into tablib:

```
import tablib

my_dataset = tablib.Dataset()
my_dataset.xlsx = open('input_file.xlsx', 'rb').read()
print(my_dataset)
```

and returns something like this:

```
Email                |Id   |Name                       
---------------------|-----|---------

my_name@tablib.com   |0    |My Name          
my_name1@tablib.com  |1    |My Name1               
my_name2@tablib.com  |2    |My Name2          
my_name3@tablib.com  |3    |My Name3
```

Answer (score 2):

It works like this

```
import tablib
f = open('my_file.xlsx', 'rb')
data = tablib.import_set(f.read(), format='xlsx')
data[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

While earlier answers may be correct at that time, I'm afraid they are now obsolete due to improvements/changes in `tablib` library, Here's the code that worked for me and hope this helps the next person:

```
#Importing tablib library
import tablib
my_dataset = tablib.Dataset()
my_dataset.xlsx = open('my_file.xlsx').read()
print my_dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your `dbf` example extension. (Which got me on the path of getting my own example working. Thanks!)

1. The file should be [opened in binary mode](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open).
2. The data should be assigned into the associated `Dataset` representation.

```
def loadXLS(self):
  self.data = tablib.Dataset()
  self.data.xls = open('Data.xls', 'rb').read()
  return self.data
```

I have been unable to get `.xlsx` working and suspect it requires a specialized input process. I'll be looking into the [`django_import_export` `XLSX` dataset creation](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/650d5f1c57de17ed51933a40016d738a2e0bc6a9/import_export/formats/base_formats.py#L204).